# dat.gui remove and add listener

Tags: dat.gui

Lets say i have 2 objects on my scene and sometimes i want the listener on the first and sometimes on the second object. So i did:

```
    gui = new GUI( { width: 330 } );
    box1 = gui.addFolder('ObjectScale');
    item1 = box1.add(myObject.scale, 'x', 0, 3).name('Width').listen();
```

Now i want the listener on my second object, so the variable "myobject" changes to "myobject2".
i tried:

```
    box1.remove(item1);
```

Here appears this Error "HierarchyRequestError".

Then i wanted to just do this:

```
    item1 = box1.add(myObject2.scale, 'x', 0, 3).name('Width').listen();
```

Questions: Why is there an Error, how can i cancel the listener and make one to the second object? How can i just remove the item? (i need to do this, too)

Answer (score 0):

i managed doing it with this.

```
    gui.removeFolder(box1);
    box1 = gui.addFolder('ObjectScale');
```

Problem: All listeners will be deleted. For me thats fine. More Code but fine.